# Run Code on Button Click or if query strings present

Tags: vb.net, string, postback

Right now I have a search box that when the search button is clicked, the code on the vb file runs (analyzing and processing the search query) and then redirects to a search results page.  I want to have a search box on the search results page that will redirect to the search page with a query string containing the search query.

So my question is, can I add to this:

```
Protected Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
```

Where it runs that code when that button is pressed, or if there is ?query=search-query string present in the url?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Page Load Event Handler:

```
If Not Request.QueryString("query") Is Nothing Then

   btnSearch_Click(Nothing, Nothing)

End If
```

If you don't want it to do this on postbacks, make sure you code for it.